# Laravel 5.5 исключить middleware слои для методов resource контроллеров

Tags: laravel, symfony, маршрутизация, laravel5, middleware

Ситуация такая:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:moderator'], function () {
        Route::resources([
            'news'      => 'NewsController',
            'videos'    => 'VideoController'
        ]);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {
        Route::resources([
            'users'  => 'UserController',
            'roles'  => 'RolesController'
        ]);
    });

    ...
});
```

Как сделать, так, чтобы некоторые методы `index` и `show` ресурсных контроллеров, таких как `NewsController`, `VideoController`, `UsersController` и др, были исключением для `middleware` слоёв?

Comment: В самом контроллере в конструкторе укажите: `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);` к примеру, тогда для методов `index(), show()` `middleware` не будет действовать..

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы исключить отдельный метод контроллера из определенного `middleware`, в конструкторе контроллера нужно вызвать

```
public function __construct()
{
    // для middleware 'guest' исключить метод 'logout' данного контроллера
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```